How to specify colorway for plotly line graph theme?
I'm plotting line graphs in Python with plotly. I can manually specify the colour of each line from the fig.line() call with the color_discrete_map argument.
But what I want to do is specify the default colours using a theme. I am able to define a theme and apply other characteristics (e.g. a grey background), but the "colorway" does not get applied. Why?
MWE:
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
import pandas as pd

# generate sample data
data = []
for x in range(3):
    for c in ['a', 'b']:
        data.append({'x': x, 'y': x + (c == 'a')*1, 'c': c})
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = px.line(test_df, 
              y='y',
              x='x', 
              color='c',
              color_discrete_map={
                  'a': 'pink',
                  'b': 'olive'
              },
              title='manual')

fig.show()

test_template = {
    'layout': {
        'colorway': ['pink', 'olive'],
        'plot_bgcolor': 'grey',
    },
}

# Register the template
pio.templates['test_template'] = test_template


# Create the plot
fig = px.line(test_df, 
              y='y',
              x='x', 
              color='c',
              title='via theme')

fig.update_layout(template=test_template)

# Show the plot
fig.show()

Expected behavior: Both plots have the same line colours.
Actual behavior:
The default plotly colours (red and blue) are used for the line colours when I try to use a custom theme.

The fact that the background colour does change means that I am correctly applying a theme. The problem is probably with the definition or location of the colorway property within the theme dict.

The template definition is correct. The thing is that colorway defines (overrides) default trace colors, and plotly assigns those colors to trace markers/lines for each trace in fig.data upon trace creation. So the template must registered and specified when calling px.line() (@see Specifying themes in Plotly Express) :
# Register the template
pio.templates['test_template'] = test_template

# Create the plot
fig = px.line(test_df,
              y='y',
              x='x',
              color='c',
              title='via theme',
              template='test_template') # Specify the template

# not needed (redundant)
#fig.update_layout(template='test_template')

# Show the plot
fig.show()


You can also set the template as default, in which case you don't need to specify it afterwards (@see Specifying a default theme) :
# Register the template and set as default 
pio.templates['test_template'] = test_template
pio.templates.default = 'test_template'

# Create the plot
fig = px.line(test_df,
              y='y',
              x='x',
              color='c',
              title='via theme') 

# Show the plot
fig.show()

